# Google compute global forwarding rule asking for region

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a global forwarding rule. My yaml file is below

```
resources:

- name: rule

  type: compute.v1.forwardingRule

  properties:

    portRange: 80-80

    IPProtocol: TCP

    target: projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/targetHttpProxies/myproxy

    IPAddress: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When i run the command :
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create grule --config test.yaml

It is giving error saying resource properties region is required. It is asking for region, but i am trying to create a global forwarding rule for which I need not give region.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be `compute.v1.globalForwardingRule`?